# MasterCard and SWIFT

Tags: banking, mastercard

I have MasterCard. With Master Card I have received paper where I have two important things.

1. Card number
2. Account number

So. Questions.

1. For SWIFT transactions I should use Account number. Yes? (I'm trying to transfer funds from odesk.com to my bank account).
2. After transaction is successfuly completed to Account number. Can I use transfered funds for shopping through MasterCard? Or I should do additional steps for that?

**Edited:** MasterCard issued by Armenian bank whose name is: ARMECONOMBANK (swift: ARECAM22)
Mine MasterCard is Debit Card.

Comment: What Bank has issued you the Master Card. Is the Master Card a Credit Card or a Debit Card?

Comment: If additional information isn't provided we won't be able to answer this...

Comment: i have updated my question.

Answer (score 6):

Your "Mastercard" is a debit card to access the funds on your bank account. It has nothing to do with SWIFT or account transfers, it can only be used for debiting your account through ATM and merchant purchases (PIN or credit transactions). All the transactions will be debited to your account at ARMECONOBANK immediately, and if there're not enough funds for the transaction - it will be declined.

SWIFT is a system of inter bank transfers, and in addition to the bank account, you should also have bank SWIFT code and address, all of which should be written down in the SWIFT transfer request.

Answer (score 1):

Yes for SWIFT transactions you should use Account number along with Swift ID: ARECAM22. Once the transfer is complete [it can take 2-3 days depending on from where and how you are transfering funds], the funds will be available in your account.

Once the funds are available in your account, you can use your Master Debit Card or any other means to withdraw funds.